# How to compare numbers in two columns in a excel sheet

Tags: excel-formula

I have two columns - Column A has 13 amounts in 13 cells. Column B has 5 amounts in 5 cells. The total of Column A and Column B is equal, however, the amount in one cell of Column B is equal to a sum of two or three or four cells (I am not sure - because that is what I have to find) in column A. I want to identify the number of cells in Column A whose total is equal to the amount in one cell of column B.

In the below example: the amount in first cell of column B which is 22 is equal to a sum of first five cells in column A (2+3+5+4+8) and the second amount in Column B, which is 91 is equal to sum of seventh and eight cell (85+6).

[Excel Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5d3a.png)

Please help me how do I identify/highlight the cells in column A whose total is equal to one cell of column B.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This will identify the cells, but does nothing to its formatting (no cell highlithing)

Put :

```
E2 = 1
E3 = 2
E4 = 3
E5 = 4
E6 = 5
E7 = 6
E8 = 7
E9 = 8
E10 = 9
E11 = 10
E12 = 11
E13 = 12
E14 = 13
H1 = "A row#"
I1 = "B row#"
```

and formulas..

```
F2      =IF(G1="",A2+F1,A2)
G2      =IF(IFERROR(MATCH(F2,B:B,0),0)>0,INDEX(B:B,MATCH(F2,B:B,0)),"")
H2      =IF(G2="","",E2)
I2      =IF(G2="","",MATCH(F2,B:B,0)-1)
```

select F2:I2 and drag until I14. I think that's it.. (:

Comment: Thank you for your answer...I will try to use this once I am free...I shall get back to you if I have any questions. Regards

Comment: Hi Phidot...I am sorry...I did not understand how to use this formula...where should I put this $E$2=1 $E$3=2....until $I$1="B row#" and the rother $F$2. Can you please attach a screen shot of how you used this formula...thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Edited my post.. to make it clearer.  I mean... type '1' into cell E2, then '2' into cell E3.. and so on.

Comment: how does it goes?